# AngularJS + Firebase: Uncaught Document body has not initialized. Wait to initialize Firebase until after the document is ready

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

[**LIVE DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/jekimeze/1/edit)

I would like to use AngularFire to bind `$rootScope.demo` to the Firebase model.

[Here is what I'm trying to do:](http://jsbin.com/jekimeze/1/edit)

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="Demo">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Demo</title>

  <script src="//code.angularjs.org/1.3.0-beta.5/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.angularjs.org/1.3.0-beta.5/angular-route.js"></script>
  <script src='//cdn.firebase.com/js/client/1.0.11/firebase.js'></script>
  <script src="//cdn.firebase.com/libs/angularfire/0.7.1/angularfire.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-view>
</body>
</html>
```

---

```
angular.module("Demo", ["ngRoute", "firebase"])
.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

  var resolve = {
    whatever: function ($q, $rootScope, $firebase) {
      var defer = $q.defer();

      // I use a different URL in my app as you might guess
      var demoRef = new Firebase("https://demo.firebaseio.com");

      $firebase(demoRef).$bind($rootScope, "demo").then(function() {
        defer.resolve($rootScope.demo);
      });

      return defer.promise;
    }
  };

  $routeProvider
    .when("/", {
      controller: function($scope) {
        $scope.message = "Hello World!";
      },
      template: "<div>{{ message }}</div>",
      resolve: resolve
    })
    .otherwise({
      redirectTo: "/"
    });
});
```

Unfortunately, I get the following error:

> Uncaught Document body has not initialized. Wait to initialize
>   Firebase until after the document is ready.

Why is that? How would you fix it?

---

**BONUS QUESTION**

Ideally, I'd like my Firebase model to live in a service rather than the `$rootScope`, but I wasn't sure how could I load the Firebase model into the service before the app bootstraps. Any ideas?

Comment: Hi Misha, it's unclear to me why this needs to be in .config() to use it as a service? What stops you from waiting until doc init? A quick guess is that the Firebase error will be related to long polling (iframes) and other fanciness used to mitigate errors/compatability issues for web sockets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently, moving `ng-view` from `body` to an inner element solves the issue:

```
<body>
  <div ng-view></div>
</body>
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/yavoyisu/1/edit)